# button destroy after 2 seconds Tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I am trying to create a button and destroy it after 2 seconds, if the user clicks it meanwhile, callback function is called and returns "clk" value. But with the following code, button does not get created, if I remove B.after, button gets created but my purpose does not get solved. Can anyone please explain me the reason for this?

```
B = Button(newWindow[num], text="Change Direction",
                   command=lambda: clk == change_direction_dummy(CLOCK,))
B.grid(row=4, column=2)
B.after(2000, B.destroy())
```

Comment: You need to send the function it's self to the `.after()` method. Not execute it! so `B.after(2000, B.destroy)` So the button is actually created, it's just immediately destroyed!

Comment: You are destroying the button *right now*, then two seconds later trying to execute its return value (which is None, I think).  You don't want the parentheses after `.destroy`, you want to pass the method itself rather than calling it.